# GSConnect issue

Tags: apt, software-center

I installed GSConnect app from ubuntu software centre from ubuntu-jammy-universe(deb) but any icon nor any app is showing as installed in my computer so I tried to uninstall from software centre but its showing an error
[image: error].

Also `sudo apt remove GSConnect` is also showing an promt *package not found* but after using locate command in terminal all located files are of icons. How can I remove it.

Comment: GSConnect is a gnome-shell extension. See it at either https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, or the Extensions app. You won't see any icon until you pair a phone, and there is no app.

Comment: so how can I connect my phone with the pc without any gui, although even I intalled it from ubuntu software centre the gnome shell extension is not listing this extension.

Comment: Install KDE Connect on your Android phone. Open the GSConnect settings panel, or go to the Mobile Devices menu in the upper-right panel drop down. Doesn't GSConnect appear in https://extensions.gnome.org/local/?

Comment: No,kde app isn't showing any devices to be paired neither the GSConnect is listed as installed in extensions.gnome.org/local even though I installed it from ubuntu software centre.

Comment: Uninstall GS Connect via the same way that you installed it, Ubuntu Software, then go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/ and install it from there.

Comment: I can't do that do check the image attached with the original question, it's sayin no packages found

Comment: Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/ and install it from there.

Comment: But I already installed a file from ubuntu-software centre

Comment: But that's not working, correct? It takes 5 seconds to install it from the link that I gave you.

Comment: yep, thats not working and I installed it from the link u given tysm, but I was asking about the package that I installed via ubuntu software centre, that cannot be removed now.

Comment: It sounds like it didn't install correctly. If it did install correctly, then the link that I gave would just overwrite it with a working copy. Look in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions.